# Android: animateLayoutChanges="true", what can I do if the fade-out effect is unwanted?

Tags: android, android-animation

in my layout XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   animateLayoutChanges="true"
   ... />
```

When I add and a `View` and to this layout and delete it, I can see both fade in and fade out effect. However, I need only the fade in effect. Could anyone tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should remove `animateLayoutChanges` from layout XML file. 
Instead, create a `LayoutTransition` object at runtime and supply it to the layout with the setLayoutTransition() method.

```
private ViewGroup mContainerView;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_linear_layout);

    mContainerView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
    LayoutTransition lt = new LayoutTransition();
    lt.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING);
    mContainerView.setLayoutTransition(lt);
}
```

Comment: What if you want to target api level lower than 16 ? disableTransitionType is added in API 16.

Comment: What about lt.setAnimator(LayoutTransition. DISAPPEARING, null)?

Comment: What if I want to animate only specific view change, and disable another view's change animation? (assuming those two views are siblings)

Comment: What if I want to remove both Fade animation?

Comment: can we set the duration ?